# Where is tarantool SQL support?

Tags: tarantool

I'm not being able to execute any SQL statement in tarantool community 1.9.

There is a lot of places saying that version 1.8 has support:

https://medium.com/@Dimitryophoto/mail-ru-groups-tarantool-dbms-now-supports-sql-6e2636a0abef

http://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/12/14/the-tarantool-sql-alpha/

What happend? It was removed from version 1.9 and is only available on enterprise versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They changed their release policy, so `1.7` (stable) turned into `1.9` and `1.8` (alpha) into `2.0`:

- https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/releases/tag/1.9.0
- https://tarantool.io/en/doc/2.0/dev_guide/release_management.html

Answer (score 2):

I have added an "Update:" note to the ocelot.ca blog post that you refer to. Indeed you want Tarantool 2.0 now. The SQL tutorial has been moved to https://tarantool.io/en/doc/2.0/tutorials/sql_tutorial/